# Is having 150+ user fields too heavy?

Tags: 7, entities

Our user entities have about 5 fields for the public profile, and 5 fields with settings that determine the content of 60 other fields we need for our implementation (I've thought of making this 60 "computed fields"). The last ones can be overridden by the user, so we need another 60 to store the user entered values (without loosing the defaults) and 30 fields to act as a flag that indicates if the default or custom version is used (30 flags are enough because the 60 fields go in pairs, they are 30 pairs).

Let's say that we attach the 150+ fields to user entities: Wouldn't that be too heavy, especially when viewing the user profile page (where all the other fields are not necessary)?

Should we define a custom field that would integrate a pair of the default values, a pair of the custom values, and the flag, so we would only need 30 of those within a user object? Apart from having to define the custom field, we lose the computed field module, I think.

Should we offload user entities by creating a content type to attach the total 60 + 60 +30 fields, and link the user with the content type using the Relation module?

Comment: See http://drupal.org/node/1262480. I would almost consider this cross posting.

Comment: Thanks for answering over there Tim.  I posted in both places with different things in mind.  Here I'm giving all details and asking for a broad solution while there I was trying to squash the specific doubt with filed collection.  Of course I'm talking about the same problem in both posts, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats right, consider creating a new entity and relate it through a user reference field, for these types of references, the "references module" is better than the "relations module".

Comment: Thanks Firdous.  Can you tell me why references module is better for these types of references ?  Maybe as it doesn't need to create an entity for the relationship (as relation module does) it is more lightweight ... I'd like to konw, as I have the idea to always blindly use relation module.

Comment: For the record, yes, I was wrong going blindly after relation for all "relating" needs. When there's no need for fields in the relation or the relation is quite simple (1-1 or 1-n), references is a better chance, specially in terms of overheads. Relation module is planning to add a simple, more references-like field so that the module could be the solution for all cases, see http://www.drupal.org/node/1246614#comment-4856364 and the module that hosts that issue if you need a simple reference to other entity than user or node

Comment: if you want to create 1-n relationship then maybe relations is the choice for you, but as the case stated above where you want to extend the user table by adding more fields, then the user reference field in your entity would do your work simply.